# Return to pervious page after an action in datatable

Tags: php, symfony, datatable

I have an edit action and when the user click it and go to the edit page and is done editing, I want to return user to the exact page  he came from in datatable.

I'm using symfony 4 and stwe Datatable Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `state_save` in `features`:

```
class PostDatatable extends AbstractDatatable
{
public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
{
    // ...

    $this->features->set(array(
        'info' => false,
        'paging' => false,
        'searching' => false,
        'state_save' => true
    ));

    // ...
}

// ...
}
```

see more in documentation:  https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/features.md

Comment: does it added in js?

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

```
$this->redirect($request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER'));
```

Comment: no. because user may fill a multiple step form in edit action.